# cloudbees bees SDK proxy

Tags: cloudbees

I'm discovering CloudBees this week... good job !

I'm using cloudbees SDK 1.2.1 on a Vista workstation, behind an enterprise firewall. I'm also using the cloudbees eclipse toolkit plugin 1.0.5.20xxx with all the stuff. I have configured my proxy parameters in eclipse (Indigo) and also my .bees/.bees.config file with all necessary keys.

For the moment, I succeed to create two complete simple hello world demo projets from scratch from eclipse to dev@cloud, but I can't deploy to run@cloud from eclipse because I always receive an error when I try to deploy. With eclipse, this error is a popup with "An error occured" title and only a "api.cloudbees.com" message, that’s all. Notice that I’m also encountering this error message every 2 minutes silently in my eclipse error view and moreover I never succeed to refresh the RUN@cloud Tomcat apps in the eclipse cloudBees view. Everything else seems to be ok with eclipse (commit with SVN repository in cloudbees plateform, access to jenkins builds from eclipse and so on are ok).

I have another symptom with the CLI SDK and I suspect the same origin, probably something with the enterprise proxy. I can’t create any local application because I always have the error message :

```
C:\cloudbees-sdk-1.2.1>bees create kiki
loading remote template: basic
Downloading CloudBees SDK configuration from http://cloudbees-downloads.s3.amazo
naws.com/sdk/cloudbees-sdk-config.xml

ERROR: Unable to download required resource http://cloudbees-downloads.s3.amazon
aws.com/sdk/cloudbees-sdk-config.xml
```

That meens after having created any new application with GrandCentral, I can’t get the workspace on my workstation with the CLI SDK to modify it and push it on the cloud. And I can’t deploy with eclipse.

Nevertheless, behind the proxy, I succeed with CLI SDK to stop/start applications on the cloud, get info from applications and so on. That meens my bees command works behind my enterprise proxy but not for some bees commands. To be sure of the config file format, I used the SDK at home without proxy to generate a fresh config file with all keys and I appended four specific keys for proxy connection. And I can access the cloudbees-sdk-config.xml with my browser behind my enterprise firewall. Last of all, with the same workstation when at home, everything is ok with the CLI SDK.

If someone cloud help me, it will be appreciated, thanx a lot…

Comment: Did you put the proxy config in bees.config file as per http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK for the CLI (I saw your did it for eclipse?)

Comment: @Michael, Yes I'm using exactly the same proxy parameters in eclipse network preferences and in bees.config file.

Answer (score 0):

There currently is an issue with setting the http proxy for the SDK, however you should be able to get going by setting an environment variable for BEES_OPTS to have the proxy settings as per the JVM.

So something like:

```
BEES_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber  -Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName -Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword"
```

Comment: a side note: proxies like this can break things badly - especially when you should be using SSL everywhere. When using a cloud service there is an implication that you have internet access - internet via a (often) clumsy corporate proxy is arguably not really internet access, and probably means cloud services are not appropriate right now for your organisation.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem yesterday:

Downloading CloudBees SDK configuration from http://cloudbees-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/sdk/cloudbees-sdk-config.xml

I found that the solution was to disable my Norton firewall (temporarily). Now my commands are running on the SDK window command.